# How to find memory leak/consumption using JProfiler in offline mode?

Tags: jprofiler

How to find memory leak/consumption using JProfiler in offline mode on Linux production machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks are analyzed in the heap walker. Regardless of offline mode or not, you have to save a heap dump at some point. In offline mode this is done with a "Trigger heap dump" trigger action.

You can also use the "jpdump" command line utility to get an HPROF heap dump from a JVM where the JProfiler agent is not loaded at all.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you share any reference document for analyzing memory dump.

Comment: See http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2017/03/finding-memory-leak-with-jprofiler.html to get started. There are other screen casts that show the heap walker and of course there is the JProfiler help that covers it.